# How does the ubuntu Live CD check itself for defects?

Tags: live-cd, checksums

One of the options when you boot up the CD is to check itself for defects. How does it do this? Surely there could be a defect that gives a false positive? Or is that incredibly unlikely - does it use some sort of hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a *md5sum.txt* file in the root of Ubuntu Live DVD. This file contains *MD5* hashes of almost every file on the DVD. Installer just check all files listed in *md5sum.txt* with their MD5 hashes.

Comment: Surely that file could be damaged and give a false positive?

Comment: @Tim yes, but far more likely, it would give a false negative if damaged.

Comment: Right okay that explains it :) I guessed it was to do with hashes!